# LINQ Expression accessing more fields

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am really new to using LINQ and I was wondering what I need to do to the below expression to grab extra fields

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Manufacturer {get;set;}
        public float Price {get;set;}
    }

    var result= (
        from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        group row by row.Field<string>("NAME") into g
        select new Foo
        {
            Name = g.Key,
            Price=g.Min (x =>x.Field<float>("PRICE"))
            //Manufacturer = ????
        }
    ).ToList();
```

I basically need to get the Manufacturer from the MANUFACTURER field and set it's value in the object.  I've tried:

```
    row.Field<string>("MANUFACTURER")
//and
    g.Field<string>("MANUFACTURER")
```

But I am having no luck accessing the field in the DataTable.  Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Well, a group contains one or more rows, so there might be several distinct manufacturers... which one do you want? The problem is more functional than technical.

Comment: The problem here is you are trying to select `Foo` as if it were a single item (and it might be), however the group by item `g` is itself an `IEnumerable` (hence you need to do `Min` to get a scalar price). This is the problem you have with trying to select a scalar manufacturer from a multiple item set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your logic stands you may have more than one Manufacturer if you only group by Name. 
To illustrate this consider the following data, which is supported by your data structure.

**Example**

- ProductA, ManufacturerA
- ProductA, ManufacturerB

If you group by just "ProductA" then Manufacturer is a collection of ["ManufacturerA", "ManufacturerB"]

**Potential Solution**

You could group by Name and Manufacturer then access both Name and Manufacturer

```
var result= (
  from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
  group row by new 
  { 
    row.Field<string>("NAME"), 
    row.Field<string>("MANUFACTURER") 
  }  into g
  select new Foo
  {
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Manufacturer = g.Key.Manufacturer,
    Price=g.Min (x =>x.Field<float>("PRICE"))
  }
).ToList();
```

### EDIT

Based on comment "*I am trying to pull the name with the cheapest price and the manufacturer along with it.*"

```
var result= (
  from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
  group row by row.Field<string>("NAME") into g
  let x = new
  {
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Price=g.Min (x =>x.Field<float>("PRICE"))
  }
  where (row.Name == x.Name && row.Price == x.Price)
  select new Foo
  {
    Name = row.Name,
    Manufacturer = row.Manufacturer,
    Price= row.Price
  }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to Group by Name but also pull the manufacturer?  That is basically what I'm after.  As I mentioned I'm still really new to LINQ and the above is the best I've managed so far.  Each row in the table has different manufacturers so that is why I'm trying to keep them pulling from the same row

Comment: The problem with what you trying to do is primarily functional, if you group by JUST the Name then Manufacturer is a collection. This is because there could be more than one manufacturer for a single name based on your data structure.

Comment: That makes sense, hmm.  Basically I have a datatable with 3 columns; name, price, manufacturer.  I might have 10 rows with the same name, different price and same manufacturer.  I am trying to pull the name with the cheapest price and the manufacturer along with it and save this in a list as an object.  The above query works great for the first two but I'm struggling to pull the manufacturer along with it.  LINQ is hard lol

Answer (score 2):

So you want to group by name. But how do you want to aggregate the manufacturers for each name-group?

Presuming that you just want to take the first manufacturer:

```
var result= (
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.Field<string>("NAME") into g
    select new Foo
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Price=g.Min (x =>x.Field<float>("PRICE")),
        Manufacturer = g.First().Field<string>("MANUFACTURER")
    }
).ToList();
```

Maybe you instead want to concatenate all with a separator:

```
// ...
Manufacturer = string.Join(",", g.Select(r=> r.Field<string>("MANUFACTURER")))
```

Comment: Joining them is a nice solution